# Is there a way to notate "This interface will look like this other interface unless some condition" in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have two javascript functions:

`addCard()`

`deleteCard()`

They both return an object with the same keys: `methods` and `default`.

`addCard` will always have values for those keys that correspond to cards on file. I've made an interface to reflect that:

```
interface AddCardResponse {
  methods: Method[];
  default: string;
}
```

`deleteCard` will have the same kinds of values for those keys if there are still cards on file after the deletion of the current card. If this is the case, it will look identical to the response I get back from `addCard`. If not, the value for `methods` will be an empty array and the value for `default` will be `null`.

Right now I have this as the `deleteCard` interface:

```
interface DeleteCardResponse {
  methods: Method[] | [];
  default: string | null;
}
```

It strikes me as repetitive and my instincts tell me there is a more efficient way. It's quite specific so I haven't been able to find any examples or guidance on this. Is there a way to say "This interface extends this other interface unless the values are empty/null"?

Here is something I'm thinking about doing. Change `AddCardResponse` to something like `ExistingCards` and then create an interface for the possibility of `deleteCard` returning `[]` and `null` called `NoMoreCards`, or something:

```
interface ExistingCards {
  methods: Method[];
  default: string;
}

interface NoMoreCards {
  methods: [];
  default: null;
}
```

Then `deleteCard` would return `ExistingCards` or `NoMoreCards`. Maybe? In some ways this seems clearer.

I'm using typescript mostly for documentation and to make it easier for future developers to read the code, so I want to be able to tell them at a glance "Hey, this is what `deleteCard`'s response will look like under these different circumstances".

Thank you for any input!

Comment: I personally agree with your thinking here. Because you essentially have two very specific scenarios but not a mix of the two. For example, it sounds like you won't have a situation where `{ methods: Method[]; default: null }` -- a mix of the two states. Therefore, I think having an `interface` for each makes the most sense, where `deleteCard` can be `ExistingCards | NoMoreCards`. You can then re-use these `interface`s independently elsewhere in your app.

Comment: @heyitsjhu Thank you, I really appreciate your input!